# JQuery Mobile link to div on same page as dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this link on my page:

```
<a href="#advOptions" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="gear"></a>
```

It shows up correct but it should render this when clicked:

```
<div data-role="page" id="advOptions">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Advanced Options</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="stdDevs">Standard Deviations:</label>
                    <input type="textarea" name="stdDevs" id="stdDevs"/>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="numsims">Number of Simulations:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="numsims" id="numsims" />
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="term">Forward Rate Data (in yrs):</label>
                    <input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
                </div>

                <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                        <button type="submit" data-theme="d" data-transition="pop" data-icon="delete">Reset</button>
                        <button type="submit" data-theme="a" data-transition="pop" data-icon="plus">Add</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Chatham Financial</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But it's trying to instead call the `advOptions` method on my controller which doesn't exist, looks like it's just trying to redirect from the base URL instead of opening that dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your post is missing jquery and jquery-mobile versions. this might be essential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks good to me...

Are you adding that link to your page dynamically? Because if so, maybe JQuery Mobile did not recognize the data-rel="dialog" attribute. If this is the case, you should be able to simply call the .page() method on your page to let JQuery Mobile do its thing.

Comment: I think what was happening was I was linking directly to a URL by address earlier in the document, therefore all links on the page then began acting in the same fashion. What I needed to do was turn everything into paging instead of using different MVC action methods. Hopefully this is fixed in the next release.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Glad you figured it out!